# Clang parse public enum class

Tags: c++, parsing, clang

How to make clang able to parse public enum class contstruction?

```
access enum class enumeration-identifier [:underlying-type] { enumerator-list } [var];
```

Comment: To start with you should use `clang++`, to continue you should add the flag `-std=c++11`, to end it might not be supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

```sh
$ cat main.cpp
enum class Foo { X, Y };

int main() { }
$ c++ --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
$ c++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
```

Comment: I guess `-std=c++11` is what the OP expected.